# Solr - match comma separated ids

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene

In mysql, I have a column `ids varchar(255)`, it's comma separated int values.
e.g `1,3,5,7`.

When search via `Solr`, user will provide a single `id`, e.g `3`, then it should be able to found rows whose `ids` column contain value `3`.

**The question is:**

How should I import that data via DIH, and define the field in solr? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your data-import.xml (if you named it that way) you can make use of [the built-in RegexTransformer](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#RegexTransformer)

```xml
<entity name="foo" transformer="RegexTransformer" query="select list_of_ids from foo"/>
   <field column="splittedIDs" splitBy="," sourceColName="list_of_ids"/>
</entity>
```

As you can see, you need to

- add `transformer="RegexTransformer"` for the entity
- add `splitBy=","` for the field in question

In your schema.xml the according field needs to be `multivalued="true"`. People tend to forget that and ask why onle the first/last value is stored.

Comment: After consider, It's better for me to store the ids in an extra table. I asked another question, could you also take a look, thx. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263896/solr-dih-define-import-one-to-many-field

Answer (score 2):

As you have specified your data is comma separated sequence of numbers. You can use the following FieldType configuration.

```
<fieldType name="comma_numbers" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" />
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

If your data containes other then numbers then you might need to tweak the `WordDelimiterFilterFactory` filter in the configuration.

[image: Analysis of the data and fieldType]

Comment: After consider, It's better for me to store the ids in an extra table. I asked another question, could you also take a look, thx. Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263896/solr-dih-define-import-one-to-many-field