# Solr - DIH define & import many-to-many field

Tags: mysql, solr, lucene, dih

I've two MySQL tables `book` and `author`, they have `many-to-many` relationship, done via `book_author_mapper` whose row contain columns `book_id` / `author_id`.

In Solr, I have a query to get book list, for each book I need to get an array of `author_id` for the book.

Currently, I am thinking about to use a multi-valued field to store book ids.

**My question is:**

- How to define the field, and how to write the SQL in DIH, it seems need multiple SQL, right? Thx.
- If I want to get not just the `author_id` list, but as well as `author_name` for each `author_id`, is that possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is your schema, how is your data-import.xml? This is no give me the code place :)

Comment: Have you checked the [full sample in the Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example)? They also have tackled a n:m relation there. The table `item_category` is their relation table.

Comment: @cheffe I would check the solr wiki & doc first, thanks.

Comment: @cheffe I have checked doc, and might found a solution, and gave an answer, I hope that's correct, could u take a look, or give an answer to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

After viewing doc & googling, I have kind solved the problem.

### Tables

- book
- author
- book_author_map (this is the middle table for many-to-many relationship)

### DIH config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dataConfig>
    <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?characterEncoding=utf8&amp;zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" user="root"
        password="123456" />
    <document>
        <entity name="book" pk="id"
            query="SELECT * FROM book where status = 0 limit 200000;"
            deltaImportQuery="SELECT * FROM book where status = 0 and id='${dih.delta.id}' limit 200000;"
            deltaQuery="select id from book where status = 0 and CONVERT_TZ(`update_date`, @@session.time_zone, '+00:00')  &gt; '${dih.last_index_time}'"
        >
            <entity name="author"
                query="SELECT au.cn_name as author_cn_name FROM author AS au JOIN book_author_map AS bam ON au.id = bam.author_id WHERE bam.book_id = ${book.id} limit 10;"
            >
                <field name="authors" column="author_cn_name" />
            </entity>
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

### Field definition

```xml
<field name="cn_name" type="textComplex" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="en_name" type="textComplex" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<field name="status" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />

<field name="authors" type="textComplex" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

---

### TODOs

- `parentDeltaQuery` It get pk of parent entity, but when it is called, and what is do? Is that necessary?
- Does `deltaQuery` and `parentDeltaQuery` necessary in sub entity?

Comment: That looks good to me. The only thing I notice is that you have only one `<field .. />` mapping in your dih-config, but you do declare 4 fields in total in your schema. But it works as desired?

Comment: Yes, it's working as desired, the column name of sql result has the same name as <field>'s `name` property, so it's ok to ignore them, but as you said, I think it's a good practice to put all <field> inside proper <entity>.